# How to extend multiple bases or conditional {% extends %} in one html page in django?

Tags: python, django

```
{% if request.user.profile.emp_desi in qa_list %}
  {% extends "qa_base.html" %}
{% elif request.user.profile.emp_desi in mgr_list %}
  {% extends "manager_base.html" %}
{% else %}
  {% extends "common_base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

How can I solve this problem??
based on designation I want to extend different different bases.

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: @rahul.m it says "Invalid block tag on line 3: 'elif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **include**

> You need to create a directory and template layout in such a way that
> you will have one base and multiple includes.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
{% if request.user.profile.emp_desi in qa_list %}
  {% include "qa_base.html" %}
{% elif request.user.profile.emp_desi in mgr_list %}
  {% include "manager_base.html" %}
{% else %}
  {% include "common_base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I tried include but the template layout is getting messed.